# How to access class method from view in asp.net mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, methods

I have controller : RecruitmentController.cs
and i have method/action : cekrecomended

```
    public string cekrecomended(string id)
    {
        id = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(id);
        string ada = "false";
        string jurusan = Session["Jurusan"].ToString();
        string pendidikan = Session["Pendidikan"].ToString();
        int usia = Convert.ToInt16(Session["Usia"]);
        string kelamin = Session["Kelamin"].ToString();
        double nilai = Convert.ToDouble(Session["Nilai"]);
        var data = (from c in db.ViewVacancyJabatanPerusahaans
                    where
                        c.Pendidikan.Contains(pendidikan) &&
                        (c.Jurusan.Contains(jurusan) || c.Jurusan.Contains("Semua jurusan")) &&
                        c.Nilai <= nilai &&
                        c.UsiaDari <= usia &&
                        c.UsiaSampai >= usia &&
                        c.JenisKelamin.Contains(kelamin) &&
                        c.TglAkhirlamaran >= DateTime.Now &&
                        c.Dlt == false &&
                        c.IDVancancy == Convert.ToInt16(id)
                    orderby c.IDVancancy descending
                    select c).Count();
        if (data > 0)
        {
            ada = "true";
        }
        return ada;
    }
```

i want to access cekrecomended from view.

```
@if(Human_Resource_Development.Controllers.RecruitmentController.cekrecomended(Convert.ToString(item.IDVancancy)) == "true")
{
    <button>Apply this position</button>
}
```

but i get error.

Comment: You shouldn't do this at all - just expose the right calculated property in your view model and use it

Answer (score 1):

This defeats the separation of model, view and controller MVC is based on - in your view you should just use your view model. In your case just use a view model that has a property making the result of this method call available.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your view model for that purpose. Let's say `MyViewModel` is the class of your model, add a boolean property named `IsRecommended`

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // all of the other properties
    // ....

    public bool IsRecommended { get; set; }
}
```

Set the value of `IsRecommended` in your controller action method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

    // other codes here
    // ...

    model.IsRecommended = ....; // logic from cekrecomended method here

    return View(model);
}
```

Make sure you have this syntax at the top of your view

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and determine whether the "Apply this position" button will be displayed or not based on the value of `IsRecommended` property as below

```
@if (Model.IsRecommended)
{
    <button>Apply this position</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. My problem solved, i have solution.
i just change

```
public string cekrecomended(string id)
{
    //bla bla
}
```

to

```
public static string cekrecomended(string id)
{
    //bla bla
}
```

and i can access from view.